# Get ROLL from quaternion without gimbal lock

Tags: javascript, quaternions, euler-angles

I'm using the [Full-Tilt library](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt/wiki/Full-Tilt-API-Documentation), and I'm run into so many problems with gimbal lock that it seems I have to use quaternions.

My question is: **How do I extract a roll or gamma value from a quaternion?**

I have recorded the initial state of the quaternion as a variable, how do I get the delta of the roll? I will be applying the resultant number to a transform in CSS. Any conversion I apply back to Eulers still hits gimbal lock when the device is vertical.

I am using javascript to write this, I'm just stuck as quaternions seem so different.

Help!